# Why was Locke led to the Pearl Station?

Tags: lost

I don't know if anyone discusses **Lost** anymore, but my question is this: Locke with Boone and later with Eko are led by dreams to the plane above the Pearl Station.

What was Locke meant to find there? Note that in the second season he was led there after finding the Swan. Who is responsible for the dreams? The man in black?

Comment: Is lost on topic here? I would guess this is more suited to http://movies.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BitNinja Sorry I did not think about that, I guess thought I was of interest to science fiction fans.

Comment: I think LOST is squarely in SF&F

Comment: @HorusKol Well there is time travel...

Comment: There have been [10 other LOST related questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost) and none of them have been closed for being off topic. Why would a show dealing with mystical energies, unaging guys who are hundreds of years old, shapeshifters that can turn into smoke monsters or dead people, and time travel NOT be on topic in a SF/F site?

Comment: There's a lot of ambiguity in LOST

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the discovery of the plane was for Locke's benefit so much as it was to sow the seeds of conflict between him and the other survivors:

(SO MANY SPOILERS AHEAD)

- The drugs inside the plane (nearly?) led to Charlie relapsing (conflict with Charlie)
- Eko was deeply affected by discovering his brother's body, and spent a bunch of time building a church in his memory (conflict with Eko)
- Climbing into the plane killed Boone (conflict with Jack -- this leads to Locke finally telling the rest of the survivors about the Hatch)

You made it more clear that you're asking why was Locke pushed to find the Pearl, but I think it's pretty much the same explanation: The discovery of the Pearl station led to a pretty basic argument over whether pushing the button was "real" or not (and flipped Locke away from being the Man of Faith for a while). This conflict with Eko led to their showdown and the use of the fail-safe.

Comment: I was thinking of this, but couldn't put it in words. +1 from me

Comment: But was not the real purpose to find the pearl station. I thought the plane was just a diversion.

Comment: It's possible that was the real purpose, but if so it was a failure. The plane was found in "Deus Ex Machina" (S1E19), day 40. They didn't go back and find the Pearl station until "?" (S2E21), on day 65.